# Why don't compilers use asserts to optimize?

Tags: java, c++, optimization, compiler-construction

Following pseudo-C++-code:

```
vector v;
... filling vector here and doing stuff ...
assert(is_sorted(v));
auto x = std::find(v, elementToSearchFor);
```

`find` has linear runtime, because it's called on a vector, which can be unsorted. But at that line in that specific program we know that either: The program is incorrect (as in: it doesn't run to the end if the assertion fails) or the vector to search for is sorted, therefore allowing a binary search `find` with O(log n). Optimizing it into a binary search should be done by a good compiler.

This is only the easiest worst case behavrior I found so far (more complex assertions may allow even more optimization).

Do some compilers do this? If yes, which ones? If not, why don't they?

Appendix: Some higher level languages may easily do this (especially in case of FP ones), so this is more about C/C++/Java/similar languages

Comment: There is no `v.find()`, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Wouldn't `is_sorted` (however it is implemented) cause another iteration? Wouldn't it be worse in this case to iterate over the vector twice (check if `v` is sorted, and find the actual element)?

Comment: Your code assumes it will be sorted at that point, so why not just do a binary search? There are plenty of libraries to do that, why rely on the compiler?

Comment: This can't be done mainly because the selection of the algorithm must be done at compile time, however a non-const object may be initialized as soon as initialization time. Thus, it's impossible for a compiler to figure out whether a vector is sorted during compile time.

Comment: This is not a question to a specific implementation, just a general question for a WHY compilers don't use data from assertions (or similar constructs).

Comment: No compiler will ever replace a call to `std::find` with `std::binary_search`. First because it's not directly interchangable (returns iterator vs returns bool), second because it can only be done if the knowledge is there at compile time and this is rarely the case. And in that case, it is expected from the user to just use the right function.

Comment: @Nephtys I'm pretty sure when (not if, but when) compilers become so smart that they can do code analysis like this, then none of will have jobs.

Comment: This example is wayyyyyyyy too complicated. Maybe start with `assert(x>3); if(x>0)...` which is simple enough that there is hope.

Comment: I see the myth of the "sufficiently smart compiler" is still very much alive.

Comment: @Marc That is not in any way easier, because it can also fail. If x is a constant / local variable it will be optimized away anyway (by a "sufficiently smart compiler" as harold put it). And if it isn't concurrent access will make any optimization impossible anyway (which is another reason why compilers can't optimize that, damn).

Comment: @Nephtys: It's much, much, much easier.  Compilers often figure out ranges of values variables can take on as part of their work.  There's no need to reason about partially ordered sets and have the compiler know about fast algorithms for certain partially ordered sets.

Comment: @tmyklebu "Easier" is the problem. I don't know any compiler which would need such an assert to optimize such a line. Maybe you can give me some larger snippet where the assert actually gives additional informations vs. the same snippet without the assert? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nephtys: Huh?  If `x` is known to be `> 3`, then there is no reason to generate the `x > 0` test and ensuing branch.  Read Marc's example again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rice's Theorem basically states that non-trivial properties of code cannot be computed in general.

The relationship between `is_sorted` being true, and running a faster search is possible instead of a linear one, is a non-trivial property of the program after `is_sorted` is asserted.

You can arrange for explicit connections between `is_sorted` and the ability to use various faster algorithms.  The way you communicate this information in C++ to the compiler is via the type system.  Maybe something like this:

```
template<typename C>
struct container_is_sorted {
  C c;
  // forward a bunch of methods to `c`.
};
```

then, you'd invoke a container-based algorithm that would either use a linear search on most containers, or a sorted search on containers wrapped in `container_is_sorted`.

This is a bit awkward in C++.  In a system where variables could carry different compiler-known type-like information at different points in the same stream of code (types that mutate under operations) this would be easier.

Ie, suppose types in C++ had a sequence of tags like `int{positive, even}` you could attach to them, and you could change the tags:

```
int x;
make_positive(x);
```

Operations on a type that did not actively preserve a tag would automatically discard it.

Then `assert( {is sorted}, foo )` could attach the tag `{is sorted}` to `foo`.  Later code could then consume `foo` and have that knowledge.  If you inserted something into `foo`, it would lose the tag.

Such tags might be run time (that has cost, however, so unlikely in C++), or compile time (in which case, the tag-state of a given variable must be statically determined at a given location in the code).

In C++, due to the awkwardness of such stuff, we instead by habit simply note it in comments and/or use the full type system to tag things (rvalue vs lvalue references are an example that was folded into the language proper).

So the programmer is expected to know it is sorted, and invoke the proper algorithm given that they know it is sorted.

Comment: I like this to be the answer. You describe exactly what could be done with such additional meta data, and it's also a perfect argument when discussing in favor of JIT runtime compiled languages. .NET for example (and many more language runtimes) allow for such tags which could then be used to optimize in this regard (even if most JIT compilers do not do this on this scale).

Comment: @Nephtys: It's not an argument for using a JIT at all.  A JIT would also need to be taught about "sorted" and everything else.  All you can do with a JIT that you can't do with static compilation is optimise based on things that are known at runtime but not at compile-time, and that has nothing to do with your example.

Comment: @tmyklebu To correct myself: It allows to implement such 'tags' as runtime data added to an object, not at at compile time based on static typing (which would be the #1 solution in C++, casting a sorted vector to some kind of `sorted_vector` or even using templates for tags). It's the same idea, but easier to calculate at runtime.

Comment: @Nephtys: You appear to be pining for some kind of dependent type system.  JIT or not has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: @Nephtys JIT is orthogonal to a type system that allows tags.  Even without JIT in a system with dynamic tags on data, you can have dynamic tags, and have runtime dispatching of the algorithm read said tags.  But what that reduces to is basically adding a bool that says "is sorted" and having it cleared on the vector, and having the find code check that.  Automatically arranging such things (produced and consumed tags) is basically impossible, ala Rice's Theorem.  Someone has to hand-code the relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two parts to the answer.

First, let's look at assert:

> #### 7.2 Diagnostics `<assert.h>`
>
> 1 The header  defines the assert and static_assert macros and
>   refers to another macro,
>
> ```
> NDEBUG
> ```
>
> which is not defined by `<assert.h>`. If `NDEBUG` is defined as a macro name at the point in the source file where `<assert.h>` is included, the assert macro is defined simply as
>
> ```
> #define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
> ```
>
> The assert macro is redefined according to the current state of `NDEBUG` each time that `<assert.h>` is included.
>   2 The `assert` macro shall be implemented as a macro, not as an actual function. If the macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function, the behavior is undefined.

Thus, there is nothing left in release-mode to give the compiler any hint that some condition can be assumed to hold.
Still, there is nothing stopping you from redefining `assert` with an implementation-defined `__assume` in release-mode yourself (take a look at `__builtin_unreachable()` in clang / gcc).

Let's assume you have done so. Now, the condition tested could be really complicated and expensive. Thus, you really want to annotate it so it does not ever result in any run-time work. Not sure how to do that.

Let's grant that your compiler even allows that, for arbitrary expressions.

---

The next hurdle is recognizing what the expression actually tests, and how that relates to the code as written and any potentially faster, but under the given assumption equivalent, code.

This last step results in an immense explosion of compiler-complexity, by either having to create an explicit list of all those patterns to test or building a hugely-complicated automatic analyzer.
That's no fun, and just about as complicated as building SkyNET.

Also, you really do not want to use an asymptotically faster algorithm on a data-set which is too small for asymptotic time to matter. That would be a pessimization, and you just about need precognition to avoid such.

Comment: I'd put money on GCC and Clang omitting the evaluation of `x` in `if (!x) __builtin_unreachable();`.  It's clearly dead code and it gets eliminated in simpler cases.  So the condition test, as long as it has no side effects, should result in no runtime work.

Comment: @tmyklebu: They propagate assumptions back up the flow of execution, yes. But that might not be enough to eliminate the evaluation of `x`, if it for example calls some function not available to the compiler and thus neither inlinable nor analyzable. Also, it might be too complicated, so the optimization does not implode it all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assertions are (usually) compiled out in the final code.  Meaning, among other things, that the code could (silently) fail (by retrieving the wrong value) due to such an optimization, if the assertion was not satisfied.
2. If the programmer (who put the assertion there) knew that the vector was sorted, why didn't he use a different search algorithm?  What's the point in having the compiler second-guess the programmer in this way?
3. How does the compiler know which search algorithm to substitute for which, given that they all are library routines, not a part of the language's semantics?

Comment: "Assertions are (usually) compiled out in the final code." - Usually, yes. But is this fortunate? I don't think so. However, your second point stands.

Answer (score 0):

You said "the compiler". But compilers are not there for the purpose of writing better algorithms for you. They are there to compile what you have written.

What you might have asked is whether the library function `std::find` should be implemented to potentially seek whether or not it can perform the algorithm other than using linear search. In reality it might be possible if the user has passed in `std::set` iterators or even `std::unordered_set` and the STL implementer knows detail of those iterators and can make use of it, but not in general and not for `vector`.

`assert` itself only applies in debug mode and optimisations are normally needed for release mode. Also, a failed `assert` causes an interrupt not a library switch.

Essentially, there are collections provided for faster lookup and it is up to the programmer to choose it and not the library writer to try to second guess what the programmer really wanted to do. (And in my opinion even less so for the compiler to do it).

Answer (score 0):

In the narrow sense of your question, the answer is they do if then can but mostly they can't, because the language isn't designed for it and assert expressions are too complicated.

If assert() is implemented as a macro (as it is in C++), and it has not been disabled (by setting NDEBUG in C++) and the expression can be evaluated at compile time (or can be data traced) then the compiler will apply its usual optimisations. That doesn't happen often.

In most cases (and certainly in the example you gave) the relationship between the assert() and the desired optimisation is far beyond what a compiler can do without assistance from the language. Given the very low level of meta-programming capability in C++ (and Java) the ability to do this is quite limited.

In the wider sense I think what you're really asking for is a language in which the programmer can make asserts about the intention of the code, from which the compiler can choose between different translations (and algorithms). There have been experimental languages attempting to do that, and Eiffel had some features in that direction, but I'm now aware of any mainstream compiled languages that could do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Optimizing it into a binary search should be done by a good compiler.

No!  A linear search results in a much more predictable branch.  If the array is short enough, linear search is the right thing to do.

Apart from that, *even if the compiler wanted to*, the list of ideas and notions it would have to know about would be immense and it would have to do nontrivial logic on them.  This would get very slow.  Compilers are engineered to run fast and spit out decent code.

You might spend some time playing with formal verification tools whose job is to figure out everything they can about the code they're fed in, which asserts can trip, and so forth.  They're often built without the same speed requirements compilers have and consequently they're much better at figuring things out about programs.  You'll probably find that reasoning rigorously about code is rather harder than it looks at first sight.